# UIImageView off screen in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using iOS7 and I have a UIViewController with a UIImageView that fill the screen in **Aspect Fit** mode.
In portrait mode the image looks good but in landscape mode the image is off screen.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks ;-)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the image is in the same position in both orientations. It's the same distance away from the top panel and pushed up against the left side of the screen. iOS doesn't automatically change the frame of the image for you when you change orientations. You have to either do it programmatically or use auto layouts to achieve the display you want.

[AutoLayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf)

Autolayout is a pain to learn at first but stick with it. It's a great solution when you get the hang of constraints and start modifying them programatically.  In fact it's recommended you never set the frame explicitly, you should always use constraints to position and size frames.

Answer (score 1):

As Literphor mentioned above. it is layout issue. Either use autolayout or do the trial and error (because you are not familiar with Autosizing) with settings shown in below image. That should fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

You must "play" with autoresizingMask